# Phase demodulation vs frequency demodulation using a PLL

Tags: digital-communications

When demodulating a phase modulated signal using a PLL it is recommended to use a narrow loop BW, so that the VCO does not really follow the input phase modulated signal but outputs a reference frequency and the error signal represents the demodulated signal

On the other hand and for frequency demodulation it is recommended to use a wide loop BW , so the VCO tracks the input signal and in this case the error signal also represents the demodulated signal.

Why is that? what makes an FM signal different than a PM signal so that for one one uses a wide Loop BW for demodulation and for the other a narrow loop BW?

Comment: hm, from the top of my head this sounds exactly the wrong way around. Can you refer us to where this is said? Maybe context helps understand the claim! Thank you.

Comment: If I give you the name of the reference(s) you'll probably tell me that you don't have them. A better way of responding to my message is to explain what you understand ( if you understand) even if it is the other way round , as you say.  Happy New Year

Comment: Because frequency is the derivate of phase over time, a constant post-PLL phase error bias would mean you have a frequency offset, exactly what you want to detect in the FM case. But "bias" implies "averaging", and that's a lowpass, i.e. band-limiting operation. So, please state your sources. I don't think stating your sources should be something that hurts you. I feel like even having to ask twice for sources is kind of unnecessary on a site like this.

Comment: I certainly do not believe that mentioning the sources would help in any way, if you insist here they are:

Comment: Phase Locked Loop Circuit Design by Dan Wolaver p. 4 and 5, p192, 202 and Phase lock basics by W.Egan p.111-116

Comment: will check at the library once I'm back at uni

Comment: ah, by the way, we're talking analog modulations here, right? So, the "data" signal is an analog waveform, not discrete as it would be for FSK and PSK?

Comment: Both references talk about PLL demodulation of  FM and PM